# passing a constant literal array into a function without declaring it as a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdinitializerlist

I have a class that represents a value, and can assume either the value of a single number, single string, an array of values, or a map of key value pairs.

Here is the currrent definition:

```
class Foo {
public:
    typedef enum { STRING, NUMBER, ARRAY, MAP } data_type;
    struct str_less {
        bool operator()(const char *a, const char *b) const {
            return strcmp(a,b)<0;
        }
    };
    inline Foo(int n):type(NUMBER),number_value(n) { }
    inline Foo(double n):type(NUMBER),number_value(n) { }
    inline Foo(const char *s):type(STRING),string_value(s) { }
    inline Foo(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char *const,Foo>> &arg):type(MAP),map_value(arg) { }    
    template<size_t N> inline Foo(const Foo (&arg)[N]):type(ARRAY) { std::copy(&arg[0], &arg[N], std::back_inserter(arg)); }
    inline Foo(const std::vector<Foo> &arg):type(ARRAY),array_value(arg) { }
private:
  data_type type;
  double number_value = 0;
  const char *string_value = "";
  std::vector<Foo> array_value;
  std::map<const char *,Foo, str_less> map_value;
};
```

I am only ever interested in instantiating this class from values given at compile time... for my purposes, it would never be called at run-time with variables as arguments.

Because of the constructors in `Foo`, any literal values specified at compile time would get automatically type-converted into a `Foo`, and I could then specify literals in an almost json-like manner such as:

```
Foo({
    {"number_key", 100},
    {"array_key", std::vector<Foo>
        {1, 3, 4,
            {
                {"inner_key", "value"},
                {"second_key", 500}}, "abc"}}});
```

The caveat, however, as you can see, is that I appear to require an explicit cast to an std::vector to support array types.  Is there any way in C++11 to pass a literal array of some type to a function, so that I can call the  `template<size_t N> Foo::Foo(const Foo (&arg)[N])` appropriately?  I would greatly prefer this, because requiring the explicit vector cast feels awkward, and most definitely not homogeneous with the rest of the constructors that automatically convert their types.  I am wondering if there is any other way that can utilize smart automatic type conversion to do it in a more uniform and concise way?

I have seen code like this before:

```
template<std::size_t N> void do_stuff(const char (&str)[N]) ...
```

Which can be called with string literals, so conceptually the mechanism appears to exist for understanding compile-time literal arrays, but is there any way to specify a constant array of  types *other* than `char`?

Comment: Post some compilable code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: I have modified the post to clarify my question, and have ensured that the code snippets compile this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
template <typename... Args>
Foo(Args&&... args) :
  array_value{Foo(std::forward<Args>(args))...}
{}

Foo foo(4.2, "hello");
```

[Proof of concept](http://rextester.com/XKDW81836)

Comment: This works for the case you describe, but as soon as I add the initializer_list method, and attempt to add a map, it fails.  http://rextester.com/ZDGZ73427

Comment: It can be salvaged as `Foo foo(4.2, "hello", Foo{{"w",100}});` That's the best that can be done, I suspect; a template parameter can never be deduced from a brace-init list.